# how to find port number of android emulator to send sms

Tags: android, sms, port

i am developing android messaging application i need to know port number of emulator to test my application by sending SMS to that emulator where can i find port number?i am new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to send an SMS to your emulator as well.
By default the window to send an SMS is on the left side of the screen in the middle.
Be sure to select your emulator in the window above if it is not already selected.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
adb emu sms send 5551234 "text"
```

to send sms to emulator.